# Is it possible to make row_span operation on a GridLayout programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, android-view

I would like to make row_span operation on a GridLayout and add a button to that spanned area.The view should cover entire area. But I could not achive my aim. Could anyone help me ?

Here is my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.schedule);
    g =(GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.grid);

    Button b = new Button(this);
    GridLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    layoutParams.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(3,5,112);
    g.addView(b,layoutParams);
}
```

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you tell us exactly what behavior you got and what you expected instead.

Comment: i am expecting the third row to be vertically alligned and span should be 5. but span is not working. 112 is vertical alignment constant right*